# "--INSERT--" doesn't go away with a remapped escape key

Tags: insert-mode, key-bindings

I remapped the `Esc` key to `jj` as follows:

```
inoremap jj <esc>l
```

If I only put `<esc>` the cursor is always one letter to the right, however once I add the `l` the notification message **--INSERT --** won't go away.

How can I solve this issue without removing the `l`?

Comment: I can't recreate this behavior. Does it still happen when you launch vim with `-u NONE`? (remember that you'll need `:set showmode`)

Comment: I can reproduce it with Vim 8.1.885/Linux. Even with `vim -u NONE`. The simplest fix is `inoremap jj <esc>l<c-l>`.